# Do something when all alamofire requests are finished

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

I got an array of url and I want to make an alamofire request for each url in that array:

```
func getData(completion: @scaping(_success: Bool) -> Void) {
  for url in self.myArray {
     Alamofire.request(url).responseImage { response in
        if let image = response.result.value {
          print(image)
          completion(true)
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The problem is I can't know when ALL requests are finished, maybe because the `for` loop. Even using the completion handler.
If I try to do something on getData success, some requests are not finished yet.

I'd like to do something after all requests are done, like update a tableView

Comment: See dispatch group...

Comment: I think thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you know how many urls you have (which you do) just keep a count of how often you reach the completion handler - something like this.

```
func getData(completion: @scaping(_success: Bool) -> Void) {
    var urlCounter = self.myArray.count
    for url in self.myArray {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                print(image)
                completion(true)
                urlCounter -= 1
                if urlCounter == 0
                {
                    // everything finished - do completion stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```